# Facebook Api Messenger subscribe webbook programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart?__mref=message_bubble) Facebook docs page we learn how to create a bot for receiving and sending messages through a Facebook Page.

Is there a way to connect between a webhook and a page programatically and not manually?

If my product is a generic bot for Facebook Messenger, I want to be able to register him to pages without asking my clients to grant me an admin permission to their Facebook Page.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#subscribe

Comment: @CBroe -  ohhh don't know how I missed that.. thanks

Comment: @Asaf Nevo... Is it working for you. I mean i dont understand how are you setting webhook programmatically.

Comment: @runitfirst https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks Webhooks subscriptions can also be created and modified via the `/{app-id}/subscriptions` Graph API edge.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else still has this problem, in addition to using the app subscription edge and the page subscription edge, you also need the following permissions: `manage_pages, pages_messaging, read_page_mailboxes`. The page was not showing up for me in the app > messenger settings until I added the `read_page_mailboxes` permission.

Comment: the `manage_pages` permission is deprectaed now. For page webhook creation and subscriptions the `pages_manage_metadata` permission is used. See [permissions here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/#p)